# unlang: SQL results to local variable

Tags: mysql, sql, radius

I'm trying to save a resultset of a SQL query in `unlang`. (First time with `unlang` for me, by the way, so please don't judge me for mistakes.)

The corresponding line is

```
Sql-Result-Set = %{expr: %{sql:SELECT SUM(`InputBytes`),SUM(`OutputBytes`) FROM `radiusacct` WHERE `user` LIKE %{StrippedUser}@%{Realm} and `ip` IN (`+IP+`)}}
```

When I parse this with `radiusd -X` I receive the following error

```
.../policy.d/...[+LINENUMBER+]: Syntax error: Expected comma after '%{expr:': %{sql:SELECT SUM(`InputBytes`),SUM(`OutputBytes`) FROM `radiusacct` WHERE `user` LIKE %{StrippedUser}@%{Realm} and `ip` IN (`+IP+`)}}
```

I had to make this anonym, so think of `+IP+` to be an IP address like `1.2.3.4` and `+LINENUMBER+` is any number for the corresponding line producing the error. If I comment out this line the script parses completely.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it required

```
update control {
  ...
}
```

now everything seems fine.